# Finding/Plotting average of series with non-consistent x

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a weird problem concerning a weird dataset.
Basically I have 25 replicates of a model, they all have fire sizes and those fire sizes are summed cumulatively.

So a short summary of data would be by example :

```
     fires_size   rep     cumsum
0         1      rep_9       1
1         1      rep_9       2
2         1      rep_9       3
        ....
50       59      rep_9    4000
51       75      rep_9    4075
        .... 
150       1      rep_20      1
151       1      rep_20      2
152       1      rep_20      3
        ....
200      12      rep_20   3500
201      70      rep_20   3570
```

So when I plot this pandas dataframe, with fire sizes as x and cumulative area burnt as y : I get something like this (the blue lines, as I have two different datasets).

[Image there as I can't upload picture](http://s29.postimg.org/fp0bvlnc7/stack.png)

So now a cool thing would be to be able to create an average replicate that could be drawn on top of my other reps to show well the average distribution, even better would be to be able to calculate the standard deviation and use fill.between to show even better the variability.

My problem is that since my fire sizes (x axes) are not consistent(and multiple as y is cumulative), I have no idea how I could do that. I tried a few trendline, tried lowess and things like that but it never gives me a really good result.

So is there an easy way to do that? I am lacking some basic statistic knowledges here! And can't really find any answer that I can relate too as I  don't even know how to describe my dataset.

Thank you so much!

I will post the link to the full data in a comment as I can't post more than one link

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/dncnf9hn8t9m2516fnpp9v8kyeuxjhro Here are the data